# If someone never met their father, but has various information about him (e.g last name, profession etc.), are they a shetuki?

Tags: halacha, maseches-kiddushin

In Kiddushin mishnayos 4:2, it says:

> And which are the shetukim? Anyone who knows [who] his mother [is], but does not know [who] his father [is]. And which are the asufim? Anyone who was gathered in from the market, and does not know [who] either his father or his mother [is]. Abba Shaul would call the shetukei, "investigated ones."

If someone never physically met their father, but has various information about him, such as his last name, possibly full name, his profession, his brother's profession etc., are they a shituk? (It is also known he, the father, is Jewish)

Comment: Does he know the father wasn't a Mamzer/Natin/etc.?

Comment: What difference will it make?

Comment: @hazoriz I think if there was a chazakah he was a mamzer/natin/etc. then you could ask that question about being a shituk

Comment: @Fei23 I do not understand, (I was asking about what difference will it make if someone is a shetuki in our time?)

Comment: @hazoriz I thought you were referencing DoubleAA's question. Well perhaps shetuki is different than mamzer, and it's a lot easier to have a chazakah, e.g the above situation.

Comment: @Fei23 I understand you someone can me a shetuki my question is what difference will it make

Comment: @hazoriz (i think) there are even less options for marriage than a mamzer (maybe only d'oraisa though)

Comment: @Fei23 +1 if you would put this detail in the question it will make it more interesting ✡